# Android studio/Gradle project fails to build after updating Google Play Services to 8.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

As the title says, my Android studio/Gradle fails to build after updating Google Play Services to 8.1.0 (from 7.8.0).
Reverting back works fine.
Here is the relevant part of my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65685 into a non-jumbo instruction!
>       at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:109)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:72)
>       at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
>       at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:49)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:842)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:813)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:786)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:682)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:542)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:...\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Thanks

Comment: I think it is multi dex problem. do you have mutliple google play service library in your gradle?

Comment: See also https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/HsSNWEQ6H4e maybe don't upgrade until this is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try including multidex enable true in your gradle file as follows:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
     targetSdkVersion 22

     // Enabling multidex support.
     multiDexEnabled true
 }
}
```

Comment: What's strange is counting the methods gives me 62452, below the 65k limit